Android System Design - difficulty creating High Level Design
I would need some guidance from your side.
I'm preparing for a System Design Interview but need help creating an HLD. I'm coming from the perspective of doing an Architectural Design Graph. There, you would create what modules you expect and what modules will be inside (with data, domain, presentation, database, etc).
For example, a messaging app would have Core, History, and Chat modules. The Core would have a repository to sync the data offline and provide the History or specific Chat. The History would display the chats, and Chat would display one full chat.
But I don't know the "correct" way to display this in an HLD. The best I could come up with is something like this:
enter image description here
r/androiddev - Android System Design - difficulty creating High Level Design
We have a Core block with the DB, API, and Repository inside. We have two more blocks for History and Chat. All are connected to DI, which is connected to the App Module as the glue that holds everything together. Can someone give some feedback on this?
I have read a bunch of articles on this topic, and getting all the requirements is not a problem, but somehow, I can't wrap my head around how to create an HLD :/
Better undersdan how to create HLD for Andorid System Design

There's no "correct" way to do it, unless you're going to try to autogenerate code from a UML diagram.  The purpose of an architecture diagram is to visually explain your ideas.  There is no one single way to do that.  In fact you generally wouldn't have 1 master diagram for a system-  you'd have diagrams for different subsets.  The flow for storing data would be different from the view for displaying chats.  You wouldn't have just one master view of everything, that's too much in one diagram.

So, would something that I did in the image make sense before I deep dive into the specific modules or other parts of the diagram?
